# What are the origins and contents of .tramp sections?

Tags: ada, elf

I understand that they contain [trampolines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trampoline_%28computers%29). Are the trampolines created by the compiler or the linker? What is the format of the section (it doesn't appear to be code. objdump -d fails to disassemble it.)?

Is there some option to suppress their creation?

```
  Nr Name              Type            Addr     Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
  16 .tramp            PROGBITS        0xxxxxxx 0xxxxx 0000xx 00   A  0   0  4
```

I couldn't find anything in the [ELF spec](http://flint.cs.yale.edu/cs422/doc/ELF_Format.pdf).

**Edit 2012.01.30:**

A little more intelligence on the issue. The code is generated by the MaxAda compiler (ver 3.5.1) and is somehow connected to the Ada Runtime.

The only symbol to reference the .tramp section is

```
4379: 080xxxxx     0 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT   16 A$rts_bounce_list
```

Built a linker map file and discovered that the symbol originated in:

```
/usr/ada/i86_3.5.1/lib/libruntime.bart.a(bounce.red_hat.o)
     /usr/ada/i86_3.5.1/lib/libruntime.bart.a(ada.rts.elaboration.runtimeB) (A$rts_bounce_list)
```

A hex dump of the section (objdump) yields:

```
Contents of section .tramp:
 80xxxa8 01000000 90e70708 22e80708 01000000  ........".......
 80xxxb8 24e80708 17eb0708 01000000 4cec0708  $...........L...
 80xxxc8 4cee0708 01000000 4cee0708 c2f00708  L.......L.......
 80xxxd8 01000000 701d0808 1f1e0808 01000000  ....p...........
 80xxxe8 70400808 c6410808 02000000 ac960808  p@...A..........
 80xxxf8 00000000 02000000 00000000 00000000  ................
 80xxy08 02000000 00000000 00000000 03000000  ................
 80xxy18 66400808 01000000 02000000 349d0808  f@..........4...
 80xxy28 00000000 02000000 00000000 00000000  ................
```

The manual is thoroughly unhelpful:

```
Pragma TRAMPOLINE
NOTE : Pragma TRAMPOLINE is reserved for internal MAXAda use only;
it is not intended for use in user-defined code.
```

Comment: You may need to go to the vendor for this one. I've been working with Ada for almost 30 years and had never heard of MAXAda.  Or try comp.lang.ada.

Answer (score 1):

Completely by accident I think I stumbled on the answer.
The origins of the trampoline section appear to be a protection feature, particularly emulating the Write XOR Execute feature in systems that do not have the NX-bit on the CPU.

The contents of the trampoline section are, therefore, the actual software mechanism to accomplish the emulation of the feature, as per the wiki page:

> On processors with more limited features, such as the Intel i386, W^X requires using the CS code segment limit as a "line in the sand," a point in the address space above which execution is not permitted and data is located, and below which it is allowed and executable pages are placed.

See 1) [Write XOR Execute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W%5EX)
and 2) [This discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.ada/tree/browse_frm/thread/af0c6ea85f3ed92d/d73938d276369b92?rnum=51&_done=/group/comp.lang.ada/browse_frm/thread/af0c6ea85f3ed92d?#doc_230d38429142cdf2)

Addendum:
 Also mentioned in [this pdf](http://www.dwheeler.com/essays/ada-keynote.pdf) on page 7.